# Multiple dbd on same apache2 configuration

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

How can I configure apache2 to read multiple database and have multiple dbd maps on the same domain?

Example. I want this two htaccess lines to be both working:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${firstmap:$1} [nc,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${secondmap:$1} [nc,L]
```

(ignore the same matching pattern)

Comment: "multiple dbd maps on the same domain?" - Exactly the same way you set up the first one. (?) "(ignore tha same matching pattern)" - I'm finding it very hard to get past that!

Comment: So, if you have two map names how do you define two different DBDParams, each on a differente database with different users?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that's possible (on the same "hostname"). `DBDParams` is defined once per vhost and the connection can't be "named" in any way AFAIK? The only workaround I see would be to create a separate vhost for another subdomain on "the same domain" in which you would define the second DBs params. This is a limitation of mod_dbd. mod_rewrite allows additional "options" to be set, but mod_dbd doesn't accept any AFAIK.